# NSToolbar in the NSPreferencePane

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, toolbar, system-preferences

I'm trying to implement my app's settings. So I implement Preference Pane but I need to insert Toolbar to it. That is how looks my IB:
[image: IB]
And this is how looks my pane from System Preferences:
[image: System Preferences]
You see, my window new height = old height - toolbar height. This is my first time I work with toolbar and prefpane, can you answer is there any restriction to use toolbar iside of prefpane?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The System Preferences application already sets a window toolbar so you cannot have a toolbar in your preferences pane.

I recommend using tabs; look at the NSTabView and NSTabViewItem classes.

Note that NSTabView does not actually require tabs to be displayed (though I recommend making tabs visible to the user).  You can configure NSTabView to have no tab frame and still take advantage of it for panel-swapping.